# Electrical reverse lights stay on

Tags: electrical, transmission, wiring, tail-lights

We recently purchased a restored 1971 chevelle ss. They did an excellent job. I just noticed that the reverse lights are always on and assume it something with the switch. Where might I look for the switch. It has a 350 automatic with a center consile three speed shifter.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a switch the Neutral Safety Switch (NSS) and reverse switch located at the shifter in the center console.